# OSの表示言語を調べる方法はありますか？

Tags: android, ios, monaca

OSの言語モードを調べる方法はありますか？
一応、ドキュメントを探したものの見つけられませんでした。

OSの設定に合わせてメッセージ（日本語 or 英語）を表示させたいと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

Monaca(Cordova)だと [navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/globalization/#navigator-globalization-getpreferredlanguage) が使えそうですね。

Comment: miyさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。できました。